# Data not saved to disk after using socket timeout to break the loop in vscode

Tags: python, sockets, visual-studio-code

### Objective

Get the data from a driving simulator via python `socket` and saved it to disk.

### Code and Problem

I first click on the 'start drive' button on the simulator software that starts generating the data. Then, I run the following code in VSCode by clicking the 'Run Python File' that runs it in powershell in Windows.

```
import socket
import struct
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

while True:
    
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    fields = struct.unpack_from('=ddd', data)
    
    
    d = {'y': fields[0],
         'x': fields[1],
         'z': fields[2],
         'Time': datetime.now()}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=d.keys())
    
    appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data, df1])
    
    sock.settimeout(5)

# write DataFrame to an excel sheet 
appended_data.reset_index().to_excel('appended.xlsx')
```

### Problem

The code runs successfully as you can see that the last two print outs are shown below. Then, I click on 'stop drive' on the simulator software that stops generating the data. That is why I timeout the socket so that it breaks the loop. But after the `sock.settimeout(5)`, the python session ends and the last line `appended_data.reset_index().to_excel('appended.xlsx')` does not run. How can I make it run the last line so that the data is saved to an excel sheet?

```
             y             x         z                       Time
0  6374.120505  40150.996479 -1.735209 2022-04-21 08:06:16.888265
     y             x         z                       Time
0  0.0  40150.996479 -1.735209 2022-04-21 08:06:16.910364
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\get_data_from_minisim.py", line 21, in <module>
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
socket.timeout: timed out
PS C:\Users\USERNAME>
```

#### EDIT: After going through the documentation and other stackoverflow questions, I came up with the following that was unsuccessful

```
appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

while True:
    try: 
        # time.sleep(5)
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        fields = struct.unpack_from('=ddd', data)
        # print(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2])
        
        d = {'y': fields[0],
            'x': fields[1],
            'z': fields[2],
            'Time': datetime.now()}

        df1 = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=d.keys())
        print(df1)
        appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data, df1])
        # print(appended_data)
    
    except:
        sock.settimeout(5)
        appended_data.reset_index().to_excel('appended.xlsx')
```

I also tried:

```
except sock.settimeout(5) as e:
        if e == "timed out":
            appended_data.reset_index().to_excel('appended.xlsx')
```

and:

```
except sock.timeout:
        # write DataFrame to an excel sheet 
        appended_data.reset_index().to_excel('appended.xlsx')
```

** But nothing worked.** Specifically, the loop is not broken after clicking 'stop driving' in these later attempts.

Could you please guide me how can I break the loop and save the `appended_data` to excel?

Comment: You never exit the `while` loop so you can't reach to the last line. Beside your code didn't run successfully, you got timeout exception `socket.timeout: timed out`

Comment: what does the doc say on how to catch the timeout, what breaks the `while` loop, or is there a C `exit()` call on a timeout, you have a Traceback so you can add a `try catch`, or you can implement a context manager

Comment: The thing you to learn about is "exceptions"

Comment: Thanks to all  comments. But I am not sure how to use `try except` here. If I put the loop code in the `try` block without timeout, it will keep running.

Comment: If you are unsure how to use this library the developers provide nice [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) to get you started

Comment: @Grekkq, please see the attempts I made after reviewing the examples. The problem is I don't have any control on the client (simulator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the socket code is correct this should save your `DataFrame` when your connection times out:

```
import socket
import struct
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # Internet  # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

while True:
    try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        fields = struct.unpack_from("=ddd", data)

        d = {"y": fields[0], "x": fields[1], "z": fields[2], "Time": datetime.now()}
        # Also you can clean up your code as you can append dict to your DataFrame, so you can omit creation of "df1"
        appended_data = appended_data.append(d, ignore_index=True)

        sock.settimeout(5)
    except socket.timeout as timeout_exception:
        print(f"Lost communication with remote\n{timeout_exception}")
        break

# write DataFrame to an excel sheet
appended_data.reset_index().to_excel("appended.xlsx")
```

Additional note to make your code future proof, examples in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) shows that you should use socket inside `with` statement, which is a good practice as you don't have to manually close the connection when you are finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still trying to wrap my head around the usage of both `settimeout` and `timeout`. I thought only one was needed.